# Extracting regional data from vector file in QGIS

Tags: qgis

In QGIS, I have a random points data (coordinates) with assign values I have plotted it in QGIS with CSV file and now I want to extract the specific region data. How would I do this? Please guide me.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Could you please *edit* your question and tell us a bit more about your data? What do you mean by "region data"? Do you want to extract raster values below your points or do you want to extract values from another vector dataset?

Comment: I am new to GIS. actually i have points (coordinates) and each point have different earthquake value for a whole town. Now i have divided the town in several zones and want to extract each zones earthquake points seperatly.

Comment: I need the data again in CSV or Excel format. I just need the help of qgis for its distribution in different zones.

Answer (score 1):

Draw a polygon for your region and "clip" your point layer with that. Then rightclick the resulting layer and "save as" CSV file.

Comment: I am clipping my data points but the clipped layer is empty. I tried again and again but same problem